# How to get folder list from azure container?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights

I would like to fetch all the folder and files in a azure container in nodejs

I am using azure-storage library to get blob, but not able to find any example to list all the folder under a container. I am dumping (export) my anaylitics data to the storage container in auzure. Now i tried to read these files

My storage structure like

```
ios-analytics-full/ios_06cd82e4db0845b9bef73c5b22bea2fa/Event/2016-09-29/18/270b58c-04d7-4e5d-a503-cdce24a3940c_20160929_184723.blob
```

I want to read all folder created for each day and files under these folders

```
var containerName = "assist-ios-analytics-full";


blobService.listBlobsSegmented(containerName, null, {maxResults : 10}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Couldn't list blobs for container %s", containerName);
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully listed blobs for container %s', containerName);
        console.log(result.entries);
        console.log(result.continuationToken);
        res.json(result);
    }
});
```

latest folder would be today date

```
ios-analytics-full/ios_06cd82e4db0845b9bef73c5b22bea2fa/Event/2017-05-31/18/270b58c-04d7-4e5d-a503-cdce24a3940c_20160929_184723.blob
```

Comment: There are no folders in any cloud BLOB storage provider. Definitely not Amazon, Azure, Rackspace, Openstack.  *ALL* of them provide flat storage, with specific characters, typically `/` used as placeholders to simulate folders. Depending on the provider, you can request all files starting with a certain prefix, equivalent to asking for all files in a folder

Comment: The reason for the flat storage is that folders require recursion and therefore can't scale to cloud storage

Comment: but auzre said that there are folders in side the container and i gave path format as well "ios_06cd82e4db0845b9bef73c5b22bea2fa/Event/2016-09-29/18/"

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you wish to specify `ios-analytics-full/ios_06cd82e4db0845b9bef73c5b22bea2fa/Event/{date e.g. 2016-09-29}` and see the list of all blobs there. Correct?

Comment: yes analytics dumped in container every day and i want to read that data

Comment: blobService.listBlobsSegmented is working for me but it return every thing. is there any method to filter the folder let say get only latest folder?

Comment: Can you share the code? Also please define `latest folder`.

Comment: added the code pls check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you would want to use is [`listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.core.js#L1042).

What you will do there is specify the `prefix` as `ios_06cd82e4db0845b9bef73c5b22bea2fa/Event/{date e.g. 2017-05-31}` and `options.delimiter` as `""` which will ensure that all blobs are returned where name starts with the prefix above.

So your code will be:

```
blobService.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix(containerName, 'ios_06cd82e4db0845b9bef73c5b22bea2fa/Event/2017-05-31', null, {delimiter: "", maxResults : 10}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Couldn't list blobs for container %s", containerName);
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully listed blobs for container %s', containerName);
        console.log(result.entries);
        console.log(result.continuationToken);
        res.json(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: can we filter this data let say if i want latest folder (last created) ? If i read data till yesterday now i want to read data after that what should be solution for this ?

Comment: As @Panagiotis Kanavos mentioned in the comments in your question, there are no folders in Azure Blob Storage. They are simply blob prefixes. What you would need to do is sort the blobs by date. Again server side sorting is not allowed so you would need to fetch the list of all blobs on the client side and do the sorting yourself. HTH.

Comment: Ok, but i have more than 5000 records it would be very slow if i fetch all the blob in single request.

Comment: Thats's true! Is there an application through which you're fetching these logs?

Comment: That I know :). One thing you could do is start with today's date and fetch all blobs for that date. Then if you need more, you can start reducing date by 1 day and repeat the process. You can't tell Azure Storage to get you latest blobs unfortunately. This is something you would need to do.

Comment: Or i save the continuationToken and then pass this token in next request ?

Comment: That you would need to do that in any case as one request to storage will only list 5000 blobs. But don't save the continuation token permanently.

Comment: Why ? token changes every time ? how will i track how many blob imported and request after that ?

Comment: Continuation token is an opaque property and should be treated like that. You can use it in one run of the application but you should not store in a database and build your application logic around its value.

Comment: i am facing very weird issue. when i requesting 500 blob  blobService.listBlobsSegmented(containerName, token, { maxResults : 1000 }, function(err, result) my network stop working. when tried 100 it works fine. can you tell me the reason for this ?

Comment: Please ask a new question with the problem you're facing.